# How can I create bookmarks in VLC Player that persist between sessions?

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player, bookmarks, video-encoding, media-player

Using VLC Player & pressing Ctrl + B allows me to save a bookmark for a video, but the problem is that it disappears when the video is unloaded.  Would be great if some solution existed to this!

Comment: [Create persisting video bookmarks in VLC, with VLC Moments Tracker - Freeware Downloads - TheFreeWindows](https://www.thefreewindows.com/20015/download-vlc-moments-tracker-create-persisting-video-bookmarks-vlc/)